# Using a Java Filter to change locale not working

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I'm trying to change the Locale using a Java Filter but the following code does not work as the JSP page is still rendered in English:

```
public class PreferenceFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        Locale locale = StringUtils.parseLocaleString("fr"); 

        res.setLocale(locale);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

I am also using Spring MVC and we are using are own translation system to get translations for different locales:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="com.mycompany.web.translations.DatabaseDrivenMessageSourceImpl" scope="singleton">
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Is the JSP page generating the correct content? Perhaps it is setting the locale itself, too. Try setting the locale *after* chaining.

Comment: Hello, I have edited the question to add some detail about how we get different translations for different Locales. I should have put this in the first time round.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the JSTL to internationalize your JSPs, it's normal: the JSTL doesn't get the locale from the response, but from a configured scoped parameter or, if no locale is set, from the request.

Use

```
Config.set(request, Config.FMT_LOCALE, locale);
```

where Config is the class `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config.`.

Comment: Hello, I have edited the question to add some detail about how we get different translations for different Locales. I should have put this in the first time round. I wasn't sure where to put your code above, does this go into the Filter?

Comment: See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-localeresolver for how Spring gets the preferred locale. You could store the locale in the session an use a SessionLocaleResolver, for example, or store the locale wherever you want and use your own locale resolver.

Comment: That's very helpful thanks. Would you know what else I could look at with the original code? The reason I ask is I was told to use a Filter by a senior developer where I am fairly new to Java.